# "will" as offering

Tags: meaning

Does the sentence "Will you come home tonight?" imply an offer (I'm asking you to come), even without using the word "please",
as opposed to:
"Are you coming/ Will you be coming home tonight?" which sounds "neutral" to me (Is it your intention to come...).

Comment: With no specific context there's no way to know whether *Will you come in and have a coffee?* is a **request** for information or the **offer** of a caffeinated drink (or an offer of sex, come to that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on intonation and facial expression, yes it might sound like an invitation.  As for "an offer of sex", as mentioned in a comment, a provocative look might convey that.

There are, however, several ways to phrase your question so it sounds unambiguous.  If you want to invite someone: "Would you like to come..."  "We are having... would you like to come?"  etc.  If you merely want to know whether they are coming, "Are you coming to..."